# Google Places API Autocomplete doesn't return remote zip codes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

The google places autocomplete API will suggest local zip codes if I enter a local zip code (e.g., input="94903", a local zip code in CA), but it will not suggest remote zip codes (e.g., input="10021", zip code in NY).  It will properly suggest the remote zip codes if I specify the zip code with the area (e.g., input="New York, 10021").

- Strict location restrictions are not on.
- I have tried removing the location parameters without success.
- I have also tried removing the types parameter without success.
- I have also tried removing the country parameters without success.

If I compare my results to the autocomplete on maps.google.com, it is exactly the same, except that "10021" includes a suggestion for that zip code on maps.google.com.  Any ideas on how I might be able to get remote zip codes to show?  The URL that I use for the API is as follows:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?components=country%3Aus&input=10021&language=en&location=38.0305408%2C-122.55477760000001&radius=1000&sessiontoken=1&types=geocode&key=API_KEY

The results that I get for "10021" are:

- 10021 California 1
- 10021 Tesla Road
- 10021 Foothills Boulevard
- 10021 Pacheco Pass Highway
- 10021 Fair Oaks Boulevard

The results on maps.google.com for "10021" are:

- 10021 (zip code- this is what i'm looking for)
- 10021 California 1
- 10021 Tesla Road
- 10021 Foothills Boulevard
- 10021 Pacheco Pass Highway

The results I get for "94903" work properly-- they include the 94903 zip code and they match maps.google.com.  Only the remote zip codes don't work properly.

Comment: You have the location bias set to somewhere in California, what happened when you removed that (or modified it to be a larger radius)?

Comment: Removing or increasing the radius doesn't solve the issue.  The API will start to include East Coast addresses, but it still will not provide zip codes.  Also, the goal is to emulate the behavior on maps.google.com which does have a location bias while still providing remote zip codes when appropriate.